# How can I delete video stored in the photo library?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I have saved video in to the photo library.

```
-(void)exportVideo:(id)sender
{
    NSString *path = [DOCUMENTS_FOLDER stringByAppendingString:@"/air.mp4"];
    NSLog(@"Path:%@", path);
    NSLog(@"Export Button CLicked");
    UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(path, self, @selector(video:didFinishSavingWithError: contextInfo:), nil);
}

- (void)video:(NSString *)videoPath didFinishSavingWithError:(NSError *)error contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo 
{
    NSLog(@"Finished saving video with error: %@", error);
}
```

Now I need to delete the video i have stored programmatically. How can I delete the video ?
Are there any functions for it?
Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no public methods in the iPhone SDK to delete items from the Photo Library.

Comment: So, can't we delete the video which we have stored in any way ? 
Actually I am need to delete the video which I am recording. So, how can I delete the recorded video ?
Thank You.

Comment: You should delete it from the documents folder before you save it to the photo library.